# Abertura do dialog() não funcionando

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bem, de certa forma fiz algumas alterações em meu código, ou seja ao invés de se usar uma `table` eu estou usando uma hierarquia de lista em HTML `li`.

O [codigo](http://jsfiddle.net/joaoManolo/u36xwtss/1/) no fiddle está exatamente igual o meu codigo dentro do sistema (com a diferença que os `li` são gerados dinamicamente).

Mas de forma alguma meu `$('#dialog').dialog()` abre quando vou testar dentro dentro do sistema. Isso é estranho, pois no fiddle ele funciona normalmente.

No console ele me dispara a seguinte pilha:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  service:1084
 (anonymous function)   jquery.js:4618
 jQuery.event.dispatch   jquery.js:4302
 elemData.handle
```

Já tentei alterar o lugar da div que contem o `id="dialog"`, mas nao obtive sucesso.

Comment: João o HTML do jsFiddle é o mesmo que do código original? Dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/a66fx2L5/

Comment: Oi Sergio, na verdade é quase isso. Mas no meu é uma lista. Criei alterei o arquivo para ficar semelhante como estou usando no projeto. Cada item da lista tem um ID gerado automaticamente, quero apenas que quando o usuário clique em "Remover" uma chamada AJAX seja feita e com o sucesso da mesma a linha seja retirada. Será que é possivel fazer com a lista? Aqui está o link: http://jsfiddle.net/joaoManolo/a66fx2L5/1/

Comment: João esse HTML é bem diferente da pergunta... acho que valia a pena mudar a pergunta. De qq maneira nesse novo HTML falta-lhe a div #dialog. Dê uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/a66fx2L5/5/ - se fôr isso que quer posso colocar uma resposta a explicar melhor o que faltava.

Comment: @Sergio, concordo com você. Bem, a parte de "sumir" o componente funciona normalmente, assim como a abertura do `dialog()`, mas quando eu passo para meu sistema o mesmo não funciona, ou seja, o dialog não abre e dispara um erro no console. Editei a pergunta com a pilha de erros para facilitar a visualização.

Comment: Pois, no jsFiddle eu adicionei o jQueryUI, `.js` e `.css`, é isso que fez funcionar o dialog. Vou ver se encontro o modal do Boostrap e coloco aqui se encontrar...

Comment: Então @Sergio, eu uso o jQuery. Achei o dialog do BootStrap (`BootstrapDialog.show({});`), mas o mesmo não funciona. Ele acusa `BootstrapDialog is not defined`.

Comment: Pois estou a preparar uma resposta mas já não acabo hoje. Coloco amanhã. Ou faz com jQuery UI ou com Bootstrap que tem limitações mas tem a vantagem de não precisar de mais ficheiros a serem carregados...

Comment: Agradeço a atenção @Sergio. Vou aguardar sua resposta, mas em paralelo a isso vou tentar resolver também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema e alguma confusão sua (e minha, pois tive de estar a estudar o jQuery UI e o Bootstrap para responder) é que ambos o Bootstrap e o jQuery UI têm dialogs/modals. Assim no seu código estava carregar o Bootstrap mas a usar código JavaScript/jQuery para um dialog do jQueryUI.

A minha resposta assume que continua a usar o Bootstrap, e remove parte do código que tinha que era para o jQuery UI.

Assim precisa alterar:

**#1 - junte o HTML do modal/dialog algures na página, por exemplo:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Tem a certeza?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Apagar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**#2 - mude o HTML dos botões para ter atributos Bootstrap:**

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
```

**#3 - mude o JavaScript para usar a maneira da biblioteca do Bootstrap**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // botão que abriu o modal
    var aRemover = button.closest('tr');
    $('#confirmar').on('click', function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide')
        aRemover.fadeOut(500, function () {
            aRemover.remove();
        });
        // aqui pode chamar o seu AJAX
    });
});

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('#confirmar').off('click');
});
```

Note que [**neste caso/exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a90c65kx/) usei o HTML sugerido na documentação do Bootstrap, e dei uma ID ao botão de apagar para ser mais cómodo. O HTML que acrescentei é:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">Tem a certeza?</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" id="confirmar" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S: Vi agora que editou a pergunta para usar listas em vez de tabela. Aí precisa mudar:

```
var aRemover = button.closest('tr');
```

para

```
var aRemover = button.closest('li');
```

Comment: Olá @Sergio. Peço desculpas pela demora, mas acabei viajando e acabou não dando tempo em responder. Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda. Creio que a confusão estava mesmo em definir qual dialog/modal usar, jQuery ou Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Usando seu jsfiddle de base eu fiz algumas modificações. Acredito que eu tenha entendido corretamente o que você quer.

Eu coloquei o `remove()` fora do `success`do AJAX para você ver funcionando, depois é so colocar la dentro de volta.

Link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hadhamantys/fcpk16pk/3/)

Comment: Oi Daniel é quase isso mesmo, mas queria realizar o mesmo com uma lista. no comentario da minha pergunta coloquei um finddle que ilustra exatamente o que eu estava querendo fazer, mas caso não funcione eu vou adaptar meu codigo para funcionar com a tabela. Obrigado pela atenção